# How do I interpret a \u escape code in a C++ string?

Tags: c++

I want to build a list of unicode glyphs programatically in C++, but I can't find a way to get around the compiler error `\u used with no following hex digits`

````
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int unicode = 0x2200;
    stringstream result;
    for (int i = 0; i<0x0F; ++i)
    {
    unicode += i ;
    result << "\u" << hex << unicode << "\n";
    };

    cout << result.str();

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Use `"\\u"` or a raw string: `R"(\u)"`.

Comment: Remember that escapes are only parsed by the compiler in literals, at compile-time. At run-time there's no handling of "escapes".

Comment: Are you sure this even exists? Escape sequences are used in string *literals* to emit *single* characters. If the input is unicode, there's nothing to interpret or decode. Just use the *correct* character and string types, eg `char16_t` , `char32_t`, and in older C++ standards, `char` for UTF8. String types are `std:u16string` etc

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? If you want to create a Unicode string, just use the [correct string literal prefix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), eg `u8"∀"` or `u"∀"` or `u8"\u2200` etc

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain what output you expect for this program

Answer (score 1):

It is used to indicate Universal Character name. From [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/69ze775t(v=vs.60)) source we can see a more detailed description:

> In character literals and native (non-raw) string literals, any character may be represented by a universal character name. Universal character names are formed by a prefix \U followed by an eight-digit Unicode code point, or by a prefix \u followed by a four digit Unicode code point. All eight or four digits, respectively, must be present to make a well-formed universal character name.

The error that you get is likely due to the absence of a variable value. I do not see where the `hex` is declared in provided context.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

I did find a way to increment one glyph at a time ( I am referring to this list https://unicode-table.com/en/#arrows )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::string data = "\u2200";
    data[2] += 1;

    cout << "Starting glyph 2200-> \u2200 \n" 
    << "Expected glyph 2201-> \u2201 \n"
    << "Resulting glyph is-> " << data << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be downvoted. It's not only the wrong type, it works by making too many unsafe assumptions. First, it assumes UTF8. That encoding uses a varying number of bytes though. What would happen if that character used *two* bytes in UTF8, like the European regions do? If you try `Ø` or `Ω` this code will crash. English uses just 1 byte. Second, by only incrementing the *last* byte, it will end producing the wrong characters at the end of the range.

Comment: Short version: this code will crash with Dannish (or English) text

Comment: this code excerpt is not intended to be 'safe' - it is a hack for spitting out to the command line, so thanks for pointing out how someone should do it more seriously in an app. Downvote it if you like, but it still could be useful for someone